# Iphone disable ear headphone button

Tags: iphone

I'm using MPMoviePlayerController to play a video when application starts. The problem is that when i press the earmic button the movies pauses. I can't use method resume in the MPMoviePlayerController because the application will crash and i don't know how to disable the button function.

Thanks,
Raxvan

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to prevent it from responding to presses of the play/pause button on the headphone controls, but you should be able to receive notification of the pause via the `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification` notification, and then use the `play` method to resume.

See the [MPMoviePlayerController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html) and the [MPMediaPlayback protocol reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MPMediaPlayback) for details.

Comment: This would break the player's functionality. Anything that changes the player's state would cause it to resume playing, breaking scrubbing back and forth and pausing using the native UI of the player.

Comment: When the notification is received, the playbackState property of the movie player object could be inspected to see if it is paused (MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused) before resuming it. Of course it should not just blindly call play.

Comment: I receive the notification by the playback state but i can't just cal play, it doesn't work.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Does the app crash? Does it fail to compile? What error messages do you receive when running the app while connected to the debugger?

Comment: the app freezes because the move gets paused.

Comment: When you receive the notification, it should be possible to resume the movie. Have you tried stepping through the code in the debugger to see what is happening?